# I am trying to change the format of a column to '%Y-%m-%d

Tags: pandas, formatting, percentage

This is my current dataset

```
  Num Name Type Status Current %  Next Milestone\nDate 
   1   sam  -    Open     54%     2023-01-13 00:00:00
   2   Dave -    Open     54%     2023-01-13 00:00:00
   3   Jake -    Open     45%     2023-01-13 00:00:00
   4   Oli  -    Open     30%     2023-01-13 00:00:00
```

i would like it to show

```
  Num Name Type Status Current %  Next Milestone\nDate 
   1   sam  -    Open     54%       13-01-2023 
   2   Dave -    Open     54%       13-01-2023 
   3   Jake -    Open     45%       13-01-2023 
   4   Oli  -    Open     30%       13-01-2023
```

i then plan on filtering for the current week (i dont know how to do this yet) and send an email.
i have a working script for sending n email, however i want to ensure that the formatting is kept.

```
 body = df.to_html()
 outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
 new_mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
 new_mail.subject = 'Daily Landscape' + datetime.now().strftime('%#d %b %Y %H:%M')
 new_mail.To = "EMAIL ADDRESS"
 new_mail.HTMLBody = "<h1> TEXT" + (body) +  "\nKind regards, \nNAME <h1>" 
 new_mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

get todays date and store the date one week from today's date.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta   
    
today = date.today()
week_prior =  today - timedelta(weeks=1)
    
df_last_week = df[df['Next Milestone\nDate'] <= week_prior]
```

Comment: Hi, this didnt work for me #TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: @viktor Also i would like the current week not the last week

Comment: I´m sure you meant to tag @chirath-bandara who wrote the answer. I simply fixed some formatting.

Comment: yes, @chirath-bandara

Comment: NameError: name 'date' is not defined